# SQL exception returns from query

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle11g

I am using oracle SQL developer and I am writing a query in my java web application but it returns an exception.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
```

my query:

```
String query = "select firstname, lastname from members where sex='"+gender +"' and marital='"+marital_status+"';";
```

where sex and marital are columns in the table and gender and marital_status are input strings

Comment: What's the exception details?

Comment: Edited since you said `i am using oracle SQL developer`. choose the tag properly.

Comment: @Rahul SQL syntax error

Comment: Can you post the entire error. your posted query looks fine to me.

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)

Comment: What are the values of gender and marital_status? looks like you have a special character in your query.

Comment: @Rahul for gender (male/female) for marital_status (single/engaged/married)

Comment: Error is coming for this query. Check your code, there must be some other query which is throwing the exception.

Comment: @Rahul i am only having this query :)

Comment: @yoyoriri: You should sanitize input values before putting them into query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon `;` from your query string as pointed below

```
String query = "select firstname, lastname from members 
where sex='"+gender +"' and marital='"+marital_status+"';";
                                                        <--this one
```

It should be

```
String query = "select firstname, lastname from members where sex='"+gender +"' and marital='"+marital_status+"'";
```

Comment: still getting the same exception :(

Comment: Strange! what if you run with hard coded value like `String query = "select firstname, lastname from members where sex='male' and marital='single'";`?

Comment: One last suggestion; print query in your code and see how the `String query` is formed with the variable value.

Comment: i cant understand the last suggestion .. sorry

Comment: I mean echo/println the `string query` to see what's it's value at run time.

Comment: it's value is the same like the input

Comment: Sorry, I am out of idea. You may have to debug a bit more.

Comment: @yoyoriri, hope you have solved the issue. Even though I didn't given exact solution but tried giving you pointers to help debugging. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you to fix the problem.